# Is there a way to mark metadata as read only in Excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, excel-2010, excel-2007

We have a use case to generate Read-Only(such as the document Creation date or Number of characters) metadata for Msexcel file.
But whatever metadata we generate using java(apache poi) is editable.
I tried adding metadata in custom , but this also editable .

Can some one hel me out in finding a way to mark part of metadata as readonly in excel file

Comment: Are you going to add metadata in a sheet in the Excel ?

Comment: Try this https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#protectSheet%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Hi Raj, Were you able to find an answer for this?